# how to count same rating from field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem counting ratings in SQL. This is what my data looks like:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN5J7.png)

```
 CREATE TABLE `restaurant` (
  `id_restaurant` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_restaurant`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `restaurant`(`id_restaurant`,`name`) values (1,'Mc Donald');
insert  into `restaurant`(`id_restaurant`,`name`) values (2,'KFC');

    CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `user`(`id_user`,`userName`) values (1,'Audey');


    CREATE TABLE `factors` (
  `factor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `factor_clean` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `factor_delicious` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_restaurant` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`factor_id`),
  KEY `id_restaurant` (`id_restaurant`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `factors_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_restaurant`) REFERENCES `restaurant` (`id_restaurant`),
  CONSTRAINT `factors_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    insert  into `factors`(`factor_id`,`factor_clean`,`factor_delicious`,`id_restaurant`,`id_user`) values (1,1,5,1,1);
insert  into `factors`(`factor_id`,`factor_clean`,`factor_delicious`,`id_restaurant`,`id_user`) values (2,0,5,1,1);
insert  into `factors`(`factor_id`,`factor_clean`,`factor_delicious`,`id_restaurant`,`id_user`) values (3,1,5,1,1);
insert  into `factors`(`factor_id`,`factor_clean`,`factor_delicious`,`id_restaurant`,`id_user`) values (4,3,3,1,1);
```

And the result should be like this, Show all ratings (1,2,3,4,5) and their count from the fields `rating_clean`, `rating_delicious`, and `rating_clean`

[image]

Thanks for your help.

but the result i get

```
SELECT COUNT(`factor_clean`+`factor_delicious`),'1' AS rating_1 FROM `factors` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `id_restaurant`
```

[result not should like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSpWr.png)

the result should not like that, 
my question is, how to select just factor_clean and factor_delicious where factor_clean =1 and factor_delicious = 1

Comment: This site is not free code writer.. Better put your query and show where it stuck

Comment: You cannot have 2 columns called rating_clean in the same table.

Comment: You can improve this question by including sample data and expected output as text together with what you have done so far. My guess at this time is you need count and group by.If your rating values are not fixed then you will need dynamic sql.

Comment: It is simply impossible that your data looks like this. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, now i added some query, sample data, and output what i hope
thanks :)

Comment: The first image shows `rating_clean` in 2 columns, but the `factors` table does not have that extra column.

Comment: @Used_By_Already sorry, thats mistake, i mean rating_service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example this is solution for table with colums rating_delicious and rating_clean (only one!):

First of all you should create additional table, I called it factors:

```
CREATE TABLE `factors` (
 `factor_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `factor_clean` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `factor_delicious` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`factor_id`)
)
```

Next add two records:

```
INSERT INTO `factors` (`factor_id`, `factor_clean`, `factor_delicious`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '0'), (NULL, '0', '1');
```

Now you can join this tables and get results:

```
SELECT x.id_restaurant
     , (x.rating_clean * f.factor_clean) + (x.rating_delicious * f.factor_delicious) AS rating
     , count(*) 
  FROM your_table x
  JOIN factors f
 WHERE 1 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id_restaurant
     , rating
```

In order to use next colum (`rating_third`), you should and column `factor_third` to `factors`, insert new row with `1` in this column and finally add something like `your_table.rating_third*factors.factor_third` to sum in `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all` to unpivot the data and then aggregate:

```
select id_restaurant, rating, count(*)
from ((select r.id_restaurant, r.rating_clean as rating, r.date
       from ratings r
      ) union all
      (select r.id_restaurant, r.rating_delicious, r.date
       from ratings r
      ) union all
      (select r.id_restaurant, r.rating_clean2, r.date
       from ratings r
      ) 
     ) r
group by id_restaurant, rating
order by id_restaurant, rating;
```